# No Source File available AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I would like to use the AccordianPane in the AjaxControlToolkit.
I added the .dll and reference to my project.

Using some instructions to add a simple accordian pane, I added this to my markup:

```
 <ajaxToolkit:Accordion runat="server">
            <Panes>
                <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server">
                    <Header>Update Value(s) in Multiple Mappings</Header>
                    <Content>
                        This is where the grid will be.
                    </Content>
                </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
            </Panes>
        </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
```

I tried running the application and when I clicked on the AccordianPane, it does nothing.

It said to also add the following ScriptManager.  So I added it to my Site.Master page:

```
<body>
<form runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <%--Framework Scripts--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <%--Site Scripts--%>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>

<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-right">
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Help.aspx">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="body">
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="TitleContent" />
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="BodyContent" />
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="CourseContent" />
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="SectionContent" />
     <script>
         $(function () {
             $(".datepick").datepicker();
         });
     </script>
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="EnrollMappingContent" >
         <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
         </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </div>
</form>
```

After adding the ToolkitScriptManager, I get an error that it cannot find source files.

How are you suppose to add this control to your web page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have  to look for following points:

1. In site.master markup you have added register directive with Tag Prefix. 
   *Example*:

   ```
    <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
   ```
2. Make sure you have added ScriptManager or ToolkitScriptManager in the form tag.
3. Use UpdatePanel for the portion of the page or in content placeholders which needs  partial refreshing.

See [example here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_accordion_simple.ashx).

Comment: I used that example initially and I still can't get it to work.  I decided to stick with the basic controls because I didn't realize that the basic panel and div tags can also scroll down and up.  Thanks for your help.